# Fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, qt-creator

I developed an android application using Android studio and now I would like to include a native part. So I start developing this part using Qt and now I would like to include sources files in my application.

My problem is I get the following errors : fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory

Notice : I use the : android-ndk-r10e and my Android.mk file looks like :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_MODULE := qt-signaux

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += com_example_qtsignaux_Library.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += Emitter.cpp #class using qtcreator and containing QObject

TARGET_ARCH_ABI += armeabi
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my issue. My include path did not point to the great folder (the one containing the QObject header)

To fix it I used the include path flag with the ndk-build command