# Shared library with Qmake for Android

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator, qmake

I developed a android application and would like to add native code in it using qt-creator and qt framework

I tried to simply add my sources files but get Fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory.

So I asked myself if I could use qmake to generate a shared library usable on Android?

Thks in advance

Comment: You can create shared libraries for Android with both `qmake` and `cmake`. However I don't think that's the problem here. How do you build your application?  It seems to me that you are not linking to the Qt libraries (for `QObject` you need the core module of Qt) at all.

Comment: Please have a look on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833115/fatal-error-qobject-no-such-file-or-directory (I use android-studio and the ndk-build script). I think you're right but I don't know how to include the core module in my app.

Comment: That question (again yours) is basically the same as this one. Avoid posting multiple of the same questions. As for the ndk-build script - I have no experience with the building procedures for Android apps. Did you read the Qt Android articles provided the Qt company?

Comment: Yes I did but I think I will go deeper. It may be the solution

Comment: There should be a way. Android's build system is probably very similar to others however you may need a bit of a different syntax when you add the required Qt modules (example: differences between `qmake` and `cmake`)